# Linux - avahi-daemon: Failed to find user 'avahi'

Tags: linux, avahi

I am experiencing issues running **avahi-daemon 0.6.31**.

I also unistalled and reinstalled again but I always have errors on boot:

```
Jan 14 12:13:27  avahi-daemon[1773]: Failed to find user 'avahi'.
Jan 14 12:13:28  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 14 12:13:28  systemd[1]: Unit avahi-daemon.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 12:13:28  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
Jan 14 12:24:42  avahi-daemon[4758]: Failed to find user 'avahi'.
Jan 14 12:24:42  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 14 12:24:42  systemd[1]: Unit avahi-daemon.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 12:24:42  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
Jan 14 12:24:42  avahi-daemon[4773]: Failed to find user 'avahi'.
Jan 14 12:24:42  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 14 12:24:43  systemd[1]: Unit avahi-daemon.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 12:24:43  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
Jan 14 12:24:43  avahi-daemon[4790]: Failed to find user 'avahi'.
Jan 14 12:24:43  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 14 12:24:43  systemd[1]: Unit avahi-daemon.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 12:24:43  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
Jan 14 12:24:44  avahi-daemon[4812]: Failed to find user 'avahi'.
Jan 14 12:24:44  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 14 12:24:44  systemd[1]: Unit avahi-daemon.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 12:24:44  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
Jan 14 12:24:45  avahi-daemon[4824]: Failed to find user 'avahi'.
Jan 14 12:24:45  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 14 12:24:45  systemd[1]: Unit avahi-daemon.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 12:24:45  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
Jan 14 12:24:45  systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for avahi-daemon.service
Jan 14 12:24:45  systemd[1]: Unit avahi-daemon.socket entered failed state.
Jan 14 12:24:45  systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
```

running

```
systemctl status avahi-daemon.service
```

it always returns:

```
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2016-01-14 12:24:45 UTC; 16min ago
  Process: 4824 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon -s (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 4824 (code=exited, status=255)

Jan 14 12:24:44 systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Jan 14 12:24:45 avahi-daemon[4824]: Failed to find user 'avahi'.
Jan 14 12:24:45 systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 14 12:24:45 systemd[1]: Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Jan 14 12:24:45 systemd[1]: Unit avahi-daemon.service entered failed state.
Jan 14 12:24:45 systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
Jan 14 12:24:45 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for avahi-daemon.service
Jan 14 12:24:45 systemd[1]: Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Jan 14 12:24:45 systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service failed.
```

while avahi user and group is in both /etc/shadow and /etc/group..
Looking through internet for the error message:

```
Failed to find user 'avahi'
```

don't returns me very useful results..
What could cause this issue ?

Comment: Check `avahi` user is there in `/etc/passwd` file ?

Comment: Hi max, yes, `avahi` is in the `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: I have the same problem. creating the user avahi does not help. did you find a sollution?

Answer (score 0):

https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=6408 
this fixed that problem for me.

```
Go edit /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
Find the line:
"#disallow-other-stacks=no"
and change to
"disallow-other-stacks=yes"
```

> This flag is apparently what now causes avahi to attempt to use
>   SO_REUSEPORT (and turning it to yes disables this new behavior.) The
>   docs indicate this is some mechanism to accomodate nasty setups with
>   more than one mdns handler on them at the same time.